# vuejs add route after loading a content file

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I developed a CMS and vuejs App to configurate custom terminal in shops. after loading the initial CMS File from the server I want to add the "/" and "*" path to the routes. how can I do this. for some reasons I would like to have the router initialized before I load the content.

I thought I could add a route with:

```
Vue.router.routes.push({
        path: "*",
        redirect: this.getStartPageType() // gets the homepage from the store
})
```

I get always "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". 
How could I do this. is it possible to a a method to the routes.

when adding this to the routes,

```
{
    path: "*",

    redirect: () => {
      store.getters.getAppStartPageType;
    }
  }
```

I got an error: fullpath not definded in

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" v-if="loaded==true"/>
```

and when entering a wrong path into the bwoser url string then I got  "invalid redirect option: undefined"

Comment: It would be Vue.router.push()

Comment: I want not execute a route, I want add a  path to routes. the admin in the backend kann define the path for catchall. Would be great to change this after routes is defined.